# cannot pass data via viewbag/viewdata in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have `string[] ImageNames` property in `HomeController` which gets paths to all images in folder.

I'm trying to pass this paths to *view* from *actions* `ViewBag.mainImage = ImageNames[0];` but in *view* `<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.mainImage)" width="50" height="60">` they don't get value

I tried `@ViewBag.mainImage` and `(string)@ViewBag.mainImage` but none of them worked.

Fallowed through debbuger and `ImageNames` do get the paths it skipps this line `<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.mainImage)" width="50" height="60">`

here is `view` code

```
    @model IEnumerable<SmartPhoneCatalog.Models.Products>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <body>
            <fieldset style="float:left;">
                <legend>@item.Name</legend>
                <img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.mainImage)" width="50" height="60">
                <div>@item.Price $</div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { name = item.Name })
                <hr />
            </fieldset>
        </body>
    }
```

skipping doesn't happen when I write image path in `URL.Content()` manually.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the actual HTML that is rendered for the img tag? Multiple body tags will more than likely break the entire DOM.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your question. what do you mean in `actual HTML`?
moved body tag out of cycle, nothing changed.

Comment: Re: "actual HTML": In the rendered page, when you inspect the image element, what does it look like?

Comment: oh, this's it http://i.imgur.com/ZlwKOsn.png

Comment: Looks like the ViewBag isn't being set. In your browser, with the page open, view the source code and check the `<img>` line to see what's the `src`

Comment: I know this is very late response and sorry for that but I still have the same problem.

checked page source, `ViewBags` do get image links(http://i.imgur.com/OLtS1Jq.png ) and they are fully functional. 

any suggestions?